# Can We set Redis maxmemory smaller then none expire keys size to enforce key eviction (allkeys-lru)

Tags: redis

Our programmer forgot to set key expire time.

Now Redis has fifty million keys not expired and these keys used about 15 GB.

(the maxmemory setting is 17 GB , allkeys-lru).

My Questions:

If we set maxmemory to 14 GB smaller these keys total size , can we enforce Redis to evict these keys?

If Redis do so , can we read/write as normal while evicting? 
(Or it may not even be possible to do anything)

We also use rdb dump. Should we stop it before reduce maxmemory?

Thank you.